# responsive web design using layout shift

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am new to responsive web design. The output i want is div tag 
which contain dark-blue,light-blue,green,red colour should display in stacked order when screen width is less than 500px ie like this image [media query less than 500px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pd2k.png).

When the screen width greater than 500px it should display as same as the code snippet output.but the first one display like this [wrongly displayed for screen < 500px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y2qP.png).

The first one can be obtained by minimizing the browser. The html and css which i used is.pls tell why itis not diplaying light-blue and green color.

```css
.container{

  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.box{
  width:100%;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.dark-blue {
  background-color: blue;
  }
.light-blue {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
.green {
  background-color: #0C8542;
}
.red {
  background-color: #EC1D3B;
}

@media screen and (min-width:500px)
{
#container2
{
  width:50%;
}
.dark-blue
{
  width:50%;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Layout Shift</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box dark-blue"></div>
<div class="container" id="container2">
      <div class="box light-blue"></div>
        <div class="box green"></div>
      </div>
     <div class="box red"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

.

Comment: What happens if you replace .dark-blue by .box.dark-blue in CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does this look?
http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/NRZMZR

The HTML is unchanged, in the CSS I've moved the .container styling inside the @media query. The end result of the change is that at a viewport width less than 500px the .container display is block, and each div will be full width.

Hope this helps!

**CSS**

```
.box{
  width:100%;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.dark-blue {
  background-color: blue;
  }
.light-blue {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
.green {
  background-color: #0C8542;
}
.red {
  background-color: #EC1D3B;
}

@media screen and (min-width:500px){
  .container{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
  }

  #container2{
    width:50%;
  }
  .dark-blue{
    width:50%;
  }
}
```